# String to occurences and back algorithm

Tags: python

So I have this string `aabcd` and I need to count the number of occurrences and back.

This is the first method I have:

```py
def string_to_occurances(s):
    dictionary = {}
    for i in range(int(len(s))):
        if s[i] in dictionary:
        dictionary[s[i]] += 1
    else:
        dictionary[s[i]] = 1

    return ''.join(f'{k}{v}' for k, v in dictionary.items())
```

So, in this case `aabcd` becomes `a2b1c1d1` and now I wonder how to convert it back.

This is what I have so far:

```py
def is_digit(s):
    if s == '0' or s == '1' or s == '2' or s == '3' or s == '4' or s == '5' or s == '6' or s == '7' or s == '8' or s == '9':
        return True
    else:
        return False

s = 'a2b1c1d1'
last_chat = s[0]
index = len(s) - 1
digits = ''
for i in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):
    while index >= 0 and is_digit(s[index]):
        digits += s[index]
        index -= 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the characters expected to be in order, eg. `abcabcabc` is impossible input?

Comment: What output would you expect for 'aabcda' ?

Comment: user @vahvero:
Lets say the characters expected to be valid (for example bbbcc)

Comment: user @DarkKnight - I already handle aabcda in my first method, I need to convert back method

Comment: @falukky You cannot regenerate the string using your method if the string looks like 'aabcda' because the "coded" output would be 'a3b1c1d1' so you would never know where all the 'a's were in the input string

Comment: So can `aabcda` happen or not? Is that valid input you need to be able to process and reconstruct? What, specifically, are the constraints on your input?

Answer (score 2):

**Regex version**

To handle case like `a10b2`, I suggest to use regex with [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to findall number and position of them in the string.

`re.finditer()` will return an iterator of [`Match object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), which contain matches such as `10`, `2`, `3` for regex `r'\d+'` on string `a10b2c1` and a `span` method which returns a tuple contain the position of the match. For example:

```py
import re
s = 'a10b2c1'
matches = re.finditer(r'\d+', s)
for match in matches:
    text = match.group()
    print(match)
# <re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match='10'> 
# <re.Match object; span=(4, 5), match='2'>
# <re.Match object; span=(6, 7), match='1'>
```

From the `span` and `match` we can calculate the string and the occurances of them

```py
import re

def occurances_to_string(s):
    matches = re.finditer(r'\d+', s) # find all digits in the string and their position
    result = ''
    for match in matches:
        text = match.group()
        span_start, span_end = match.span()
        for i in range(0, int(text)):
            result += s[span_start - 1:span_start]
    if not result: # in case no number found 'abcd'
        result = s
    return result

print(occurances_to_string('a1b2c3'))
# abbccc
print(occurances_to_string('a10b2c3'))
# aaaaaaaaaabbccc
print(occurances_to_string('a3b1c1d1'))
# aaabcd
```

**Non regex version**

I'll iterate through the string, then check if a char in the string is digit, if it is, check if next char is digit too. Repeat the process until next char is not digit, then convert all digits found to int.

```
def occurances_to_string(s):
    result = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i].isdigit():
            char = s[i-1]
            num = s[i]
            while i+1 < len(s) and s[i+1].isdigit():
                num += s[i+1]
                i += 1
            for j in range(int(num)):
                result += char
        i += 1
    if not result:
        result = s
    return result

print(occurances_to_string('a1b2c3')) #abbccc
print(occurances_to_string('a10b2c3')) #aaaaaaaaaabbccc
print(occurances_to_string('abcd')) #abcd
print(occurances_to_string('1a3b1c1d1')) #1aaabcd
print(occurances_to_string('a2b12c13')) #aabbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccc
```

Comment: But 'ab2c3' would never occur

Comment: @DarkKnight my bad, I make it simplier without `ab2c3` case

Comment: I cannot use regex

Comment: @falukky i added a non regex version

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use a dictionary where the keys are the characters in the string because that will only work for repeated values that are adjacent in the input string. Build a list instead.

You can still use a dictionary depending on the output you need

```
s = 'aabcda'

output = [[s[0], 1]]
d = {s[0]: 1}

for c in s[1:]:
    d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
    if c == output[-1][0]:
        output[-1][1] += 1
    else:
        output.append([c, 1])
print(''.join([f'{k}{v}' for k, v in d.items()]))
print(''.join([f'{c}{n}' for c, n in output]))
print(''.join([f'{c*n}' for c, n in output]))
```

**Output:**

```
a3b1c1d1
a2b1c1d1a1
aabcda
```

**Note:**

It is **impossible** to convert 'a3b1c1d1' to 'aabcda'

If repeated characters are only ever adjacent in the input string then we can implement encode and decode functions simply as:

```
def encode(s):
    d = {}
    for c in s:
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
    return ''.join(f'{k}{v}' for k, v in d.items())

def decode(s):
    d = []
    for c in s:
        if c.isdecimal():
            d[-1][1] *= 10
            d[-1][1] += int(c)
        else:
            d.append([c, 0])
    return ''.join(f'{c*n}' for c, n in d)

str = 'aabcddzzzzzzzzzzyy'
encoded = encode(str)
print(encoded)
decoded = decode(encoded)
print(decoded)

assert str == decoded
```

**Output:**

```
a2b1c1d2z10y2
aabcddzzzzzzzzzzyy
```

Comment: a3b1c1d1 to aaabcd, it was typo

Comment: @falukky Are you saying that the input string would never look like (for example) 'aabcda' ? i.e., are all repeated characters adjacent

Answer (score 0):

As your input data is just the digits and their count, you normally cant get the original string.

Like as your input is a2b1c1d1, the original string may be aabcd,abacd,abcad,baacd & etc

Its somehow like hashing, that you can get from one end to another but you cant return

BUT, if the input should always be in order, then you can!

By just multiplying the digits in their count:

```
def occurances_to_string(s):
    result = ""
    temp = ""
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if(s[i].isdigit()):
            result += temp*int(s[i])
            temp = ""
        else:
            temp += s[i]
    return result

#>>>occurances_to_string("a2b1c1d1")
#aabcd
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What if a letter appears more than 9 times? e.g., a10b1c1

Comment: Its also something that need to handle

Comment: You're completely right, Didnt think about that. Editing soon